# Disable downloads in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

Is it possible to disable downloads for specific mime type. For example navigating to an url that by default will download a zip archive, should do nothing.

Edit:

I don't know in advance what url will be visited and what will return that url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

```
const client = await page.target().createCDPSession();

// intercept request when response headers was received
await client.send('Network.setRequestInterception', {
  patterns: [{
      urlPattern: '*',
      resourceType: 'Document',
      interceptionStage: 'HeadersReceived'
  }],
});

await client.on('Network.requestIntercepted', async e => {
    let headers = e.responseHeaders || {};
    let contentType = headers['content-type'] || headers['Content-Type'] || '';
    let obj = {interceptionId: e.interceptionId};
    if (contentType.indexOf('application/zip') > -1) {
        obj['errorReason'] = 'BlockedByClient';
    }

    await client.send('Network.continueInterceptedRequest', obj);
});
```

This piece of code blocks navigation to an url that will download a zip archive and pass the rest of requests.

Thanks to @hardkoded for suggestion to visit [github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1191](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1191).

Answer (score 3):

If it's a request generated by a page you could just stop the request using `setRequestIntercept`

```js
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.url().endsWith('.zip'))
        request.abort();
    else
      request.continue();
});
```

This is a request interception. It means that you should be able to infer that you will download a file before the request is made.
The response interception is not implemented yet. So I think this is the best you can get now.

Comment: This is a good solution if you know in advance that the url will return a zip archive. In my case I don't know what will be on the page that will be visited.

Comment: You might want to track this issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1191

Comment: Thx @hardkoded, found a solution on the page you suggested.